# Should $\sum_{i=0}^n a + b$ be interpreted as $(\sum_{i=0}^n a) + b$ or $\sum_{i=0}^n (a + b)$

Tags: soft-question

> Should $\sum_{i=0}^n a + b$ be interpreted as $(\sum_{i=0}^n a) + b$ or $\sum_{i=0}^n (a + b)$

I often see the expression $\sum_{i=0}^n a + b$ in books and wonder whether we take the sum $(\sum_{i=0}^n a) + b$ or $\sum_{i=0}^n (a + b)$. Often I can see which one from context, but is there a general rule ?

Example is: $\sum^{n-1}_{j=0} (-1)^j x^{2j} + (-1)^n \frac {x^{2n}} {1+x^2}$. I misinterpreted this, because I assumed $\sum^{n-1}_{j=0} (-1)^j x^{2j} + (-1)^n \frac {x^{2n}} {1+x^2} = \sum^{n-1}_{j=0} ((-1)^j x^{2j} + (-1)^n \frac {x^{2n}} {1+x^2})$ but it was actually $(\sum^{n-1}_{j=0} (-1)^j x^{2j}) + (-1)^n \frac {x^{2n}} {1+x^2}$.

Comment: I think it is generally meant that $\sum_{i=0}^n a+b = \sum_{i=0}^n (a+b)$. With one exception: if the expression $b$ doesn't depend on $i$ then we have $\sum_{i=0}^n a+b =(\sum_{i=0}^n a)+b$.

Comment: It would be clearer if you wrote $\sum_{i=0}^na_i+b$ or $\sum_{i=0}^n(a_i+b_i)$. Now it seems that $\sum_{i=0}^na+b=(n+1)a+b$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no general rule. This is vague, and it is advisable to *always* include parenthesis. What is clear to you, might be vague to someone else. Also as you say, context can almost always be used to interpret though.

Comment: As an example, I misinterpreted $\sum^{n-1}_{j=0} (-1)^j x^{2j} + (-1)^n \frac {x^{2n}} {1+x^2}$. I thought $(-1)^n \frac {x^{2n}} {1+x^2}$ was part of $\sum$, but it was not.

Comment: In general if the "summing variable", in this case $j$ is not part of the term, that term is not in the $\sum$. *In general* though, there are plenty of times I write stuff like $n=\sum_1^n 1$ though, where it is useful.